# Read the TypeDecorator from Angular 5 component

Tags: angular, angular-compiler, angular5

Previously, I was able to go get the metadata for a component with the Reflect metadata. Now the metadata has been moved to some annotations attached to the component.

Reading the metadata as such

```
type['__annotations__'][0].selector
```

is definitely a hack. What is the correct method to read such metadata from a component? I want to obtain the data attached to a component in the `@Component` decorator.

Comment: Why do you need to access the metadata in the first place (curious, but also worried)

Comment: @JBNizet I am creating controls dynamically, and that control needs to have a [formControl] attribute on creation. So the only way I found to create such control and have this attribute bound properly by Angular is to do compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync with a template string that looks like <{selector} [formControl]="arg1"></{selector}>.

Comment: Not sure I understand (reactive forms allow creating controls dynamically), but you really need to be aware that your approach goes against the principle and history of angular: a deployed app should normally have no compiler available (because it's precompiled with the AOT compiler), and no metadata either (still because of AOT compilation).

Comment: I'd suggest to re-ask the question with http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve because this is likely XY problem. Accessing decorator metadata is certainly not a thing the one wants to do in production. And the fact that it should be accessed in a hacky way like `__annotations__` confirms that. As it was mentioned, there won't be any annotations at all with AOT compilation.

Comment: I disagree with both of your comments. My app is quite dynamic and parts of it requires to be compiled on the fly. I am not getting rid of the compiler. I would love if I could instantiate a `Component` with a reactive form attached to it, such as the [formControl] from its `Type`, but that is something I haven't found without going through on the fly Template Compilation. Granted my question mentions a solution, but when I ask a question without having tried something, Stackoverflow people get pissed I don't show what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is the selector, this is a fine way to get it.

```
constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef<any>) {}
...
const nodeName = this.elementRef.nativeElement.nodeName.toLowerCase();
...
```

I have a component that can either be declared as an element or as an attribute. This approach lets me know if the host element is a div (when my component is an attribute) or my component's selector.